# CentOS "service network restart" FAILED - where is the error log?

Tags: centos, networking, network-interface

In CentOS, I ran the following command.  But it doesn't give me explicit errors to investigate.  How can I troubleshoot further or find the errors?

```
service network restart
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're using older CentOS, then `service network status` is a good place to look, it will show the actual output of the commands used to start the service.

If you're on CentOS 7 `journalctl -u network.service` is even better, because it will show previous instances as well.